# innerHTML doesn't work with app-component in Angular 12

Tags: html, css, angular

i want to put dynamically components like div and textArea into a div with innerHTML but it doesn't work

imaginarium is the parent component where i'd like to show the draggable component

**imaginarium.html**

```
<div *ngIf="shape == true">
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><button (click)='update()'>box</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button (click)='update()'>editeur de texte</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container" [innerHTML]="trustedURL"></div>
  </div>
```

i give you all the necessary code to test yourself
**imaginarium.scss**

```
.box-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 90%;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  transform: translate3d(-100%, -100%);
}
```

**imaginarium.ts**

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
trustedURL : any;
constructor(
    public sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {

   }
update(){
      this.trustedURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<app-resizable-draggable [width]='100' [height]='150' [left]='100' [top]='100' ></app-resizable-draggable>`);
  }
```

this is this child component

**resizable-draggable.html**

```
<ul #menu (mouseleave)="resetMenu()"></ul>
<div  #box class="resizable-draggable"
    [style.width.px]="width"
    [style.height.px]="height"
    [style.transform]="'translate3d('+ left + 'px,' + top + 'px,' + '0px)'"
    [class.active]="status === 1 || status === 2"
    (mousedown)="setStatus($event, 2)"
    (window:mouseup)="setStatus($event, 0)"
    (contextmenu)="Menu()"
>
    <div class="resize-action" (mousedown)="setStatus($event, 1)"></div>

</div>
```

with CSS

**resizable-draggable.scss**

```
.resizable-draggable {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  &.active {
      outline-style: solid;
      background-color: #80ff800d;
  }

  &:hover {
      cursor: all-scroll;
  }


}

.resize-action {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotateZ(45deg);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #1100ff;
  &:hover, &:active {
      cursor: nwse-resize;
  }
}
```

and the .ts

**resizable-draggable.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

const enum Status {
  OFF = 0,
  RESIZE = 1,
  MOVE = 2
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-resizable-draggable',
  templateUrl: './resizable-draggable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./resizable-draggable.component.scss']
})
export class ResizableDraggableComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input('width') public width!: number;
  @Input('height') public height!: number;
  @Input('left') public left!: number;
  @Input('top') public top!: number;
  @ViewChild("box") public box!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('menu', {static: false}) menuChild! : ElementRef;
  private boxPosition!: { left: number, top: number };
  private containerPos!: { left: number, top: number, right: number, bottom: number };
  public mouse!: {x: number, y: number}
  public status: Status = Status.OFF;
  private mouseClick!: {x: number, y: number, left: number, top: number}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.loadBox();
    this.loadContainer();
  }

  private loadBox(){
    const {left, top} = this.box.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.boxPosition = {left, top};
  }

  private loadContainer(){
    const left = this.boxPosition.left - this.left;
    const top = this.boxPosition.top - this.top;
    const right = left + window.screen.width -395;
    const bottom = top + window.screen.height- 240;
    this.containerPos = { left, top, right, bottom };
  }

  setStatus(event: MouseEvent, status: number){
    if(status === 1) event.stopPropagation();
    else if(status === 2) this.mouseClick = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY, left: this.left, top: this.top };
    else this.loadBox();
    this.status = status;
  }

  @HostListener('window:mousemove', ['$event'])
  onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent){
    this.mouse = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };

    if(this.status === Status.RESIZE) this.resize();
    else if(this.status === Status.MOVE) this.move();
  }

  private resize(){
    if(this.resizeCondMeet()){
      this.width = Number(this.mouse.x > this.boxPosition.left) ? this.mouse.x - this.boxPosition.left : 0;
      this.height = Number(this.mouse.y > this.boxPosition.top) ? this.mouse.y - this.boxPosition.top : 0;
    }
  }

  private resizeCondMeet(){
    return (this.mouse.x < this.containerPos.right && this.mouse.y < this.containerPos.bottom);
  }

  private move(){
    if(this.moveCondMeet()){
      this.left = this.mouseClick.left + (this.mouse.x - this.mouseClick.x);
      this.top = this.mouseClick.top + (this.mouse.y - this.mouseClick.y);
    }
  }

  private moveCondMeet(){
    const offsetLeft = this.mouseClick.x - this.boxPosition.left;
    const offsetRight = this.width - offsetLeft;
    const offsetTop = this.mouseClick.y - this.boxPosition.top;
    const offsetBottom = this.height - offsetTop;
    return (
      this.mouse.x > this.containerPos.left + offsetLeft &&
      this.mouse.x < this.containerPos.right - offsetRight &&
      this.mouse.y > this.containerPos.top + offsetTop &&
      this.mouse.y < this.containerPos.bottom - offsetBottom
      );
  }

  Menu(){
    this.menuChild.nativeElement.innerHTML = `
      <li><button>Actions</button></li>
      <li><button>Actions</button></li>
      <li><button>Actions</button></li>
      <li><button>Actions</button></li>
      <li><button>Actions</button></li>
    `;
    return false;
  }
  resetMenu(){
    this.menuChild.nativeElement.innerHTML = ``;
  }
}
```

have you got an idea to show the component ?
thanks

Comment: Could you please create a working demo of your problem? Also share if you're getting any error.

Comment: It works but what you have written there is not html, it is angular template, it has an angular component selector inside it. The html doesn't get 'compiled' by angular when you bind it using `innerHTML`

Comment: the only way you can add in an innerHTML an "angular component" is to use Web Components, see, e.g. https://netbasal.com/render-angular-components-using-plain-text-5a6377125bf3, but in general you should re-think your application to not use this "trick". sometimes is only add the component under a `*ngIf`

Answer (score 0):

I've searched and I found something helpful :

https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-dynamically-create-a-component-in-angular

it's permit to add angular components into html